# "Content not available" Power BI embed in ionic app with azure authentication token

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, azure-active-directory, powerbi, azure-ad-msal

**Problem:**

Power BI report embedding fail and showing **"content not available"**.

[image]

**Process Followed**

1. Create Azure Directory app as per standard process
2. Allow user to authenticate from Azure ad authentication and get token
3. Power BI workspace created / report as well
4. Get Report Id from Power BI and embed into code
5. User accessToken got from Azure Ad authentication successful login

**Suggestions Needed**

I am not sure mapping needed for User, directory and power BI reports. but user for login is already available in active directory + workspace of power bi as well.

It will be great help if one by one process given for exact mapping and access management if required.

```
const config = {
      type: 'report',
      accessToken,
      embedUrl,
      id: embedReportId,
      settings: {
        filterPaneEnabled: true,
        navContentPaneEnabled: true
      }
    };

var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
```

Answer (score 1):

Content is displaying properly, please take a look into [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Data-Stories-Gallery/Herbert-Content-not-available/m-p/69407#M307).

Try to submit the data story with your report [URL](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMGJmYjhmNWItYjJiMi00ZjkxLTlhMjEtOTMwODJiOGVkZWY4IiwidCI6Ijg3N2JmMDA3LTNhNjEtNDFhYS04MGExLTg3YzRhMzRmMTQzNiJ9).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but My report URL is not public, I want to access report with azure ad authentication token which is not working.